# Is it possible to determine if Chrome is in incognito mode via a user-script?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, userscripts, incognito-mode

I [asked this question before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2909367/can-you-determine-if-chrome-is-in-incognito-mode-via-script) but didn't make it clear that I meant in user script, not in JavaScript from a webpage.So I'll be more clear now.

Is it possible to determine if Google Chrome is in incognito mode via a user-script (basically a script run as an extension in the browser, not a script being run on a webpage)?

Comment: why do you want to know this?

Comment: I'm looking to write and extension that closes the tab if it is opened in incognito mode, as Google hasn't provided a way of not having it present.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are developing an Extension then you can use the tabs API to determine if a window/tab incognito.

More information can be found on [code.google.com](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#type-Tab).

If you are just working with a webpage or a userscript, it is not easy, and it is designed to be that way.  However, I have noticed that all attempts to open a database (window.database) fail when in incongnito, this is because when in incognito no trace of data is allowed to be left on the users machine.

I haven't tested it but I suspect all calls to localStorage fail too.

Comment: [localStorage works, but the values are discarded when the private session ends](http://htmlui.com/blog/2011-08-23-5-obscure-facts-about-html5-localstorage.html). So, that would not be an effective detection method for the current session.

Comment: localStorage behaves like sessionStorage when chrome is in InCognito Mode.

Answer (score 11):

> To detect whether a window is in
>   incognito mode, check the **incognito
>   property** of the relevant Tab  or
>   Window  object. For example:

```
var bgPage = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage();

function saveTabData(tab, data) {
  if (tab.incognito) {
    bgPage[tab.url] = data;       // Persist data ONLY in memory
  } else {
    localStorage[tab.url] = data; // OK to store data
}
```

http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/overview.html

Answer (score 3):

Nowadays it's quite easy to do this from a content script. Just use

```
if(chrome.extension.inIncognitoContext) {
    //you're incognito
} else {
    //you're not
}
```