# Tampermonkey script that runs only in incognito?

Tags: tampermonkey, incognito-mode

Is it possible to make any script into a script that only runs on www.example.com,  Only if the website is being accessed from an incognito window? (chrome)

Comment: This is a duplicate of ["Is it possible to determine if Chrome is in incognito mode via a user-script?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2916876/is-it-possible-to-determine-if-chrome-is-in-incognito-mode-via-a-user-script).  The answer is the same, you must use an extension to do this.  Fortunately, @derjanb has just rolled this feature into Tampermonkey.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I've added a isIncognito flag to Tampermonkey's GM_info. So you now can check the incognito mode like this:

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name       testIncognito
// @namespace  http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version    0.1
// @description  enter something useful
// @match      http://*/*
// @copyright  2012+, You
// ==/UserScript==

if (GM_info.isIncognito) {
    alert([ GM_info.scriptHandler, 'detected incognito mode @', window.location.href ].join(' '));
}
```

Please not that this at the moment only is available at TM beta version 3.0.3353 and higher.

Comment: Tampermonkey needs "split" mode support by the browser: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/incognito#Browser_compatibility