# Redirect and display alert if in incognito

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, incognito-mode

I have a website and some certain features don't work if the user is using incognito. How can I redirect to another page if incognito is detected. Additionally, how can I display an alert as well?

The following code checks if the user is in incognito. You can also view this at http://rahul2001.com/inco.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>Inco-Check</title>

<script type='text/javascript'>
//<![CDATA[ 
window.onload=function(){
function main() {
  var fs = window.RequestFileSystem || window.webkitRequestFileSystem;
  if (!fs) {
    result.textContent = "check failed?";
    return;
  }
  fs(window.TEMPORARY, 100, function(fs) {
    result.textContent = "Negitive: You aren't using Incognito";
  }, function(err) {
    result.textContent = "Positive: You're using Incognito";
  });
}
main();

}//]]>  

</script>
</head>
<body>

  <h2>This webpage checks if you are in <i>Incognito</i> mode</h2>
  <hr>
<h3>Result</h3>
<h4>
<div id="result"></div>
</h4>
  <hr>
  <hr>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: [This article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2909367/can-you-determine-if-chrome-is-in-incognito-mode-via-a-script) just checks if the user is in incognito. I need the page to redirect.

Comment: So this question is about doing the redirect? This is simple and can be done by setting `window.location.href` to the desired URL.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am no good in Javascript :(

Comment: Well, I gave you the solution :-) Where exactly is the problem?

Comment: how do i apply `window.location.href` and where do I add it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be your html file (replace example.com and alert message) :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>Inco-Check</title>

<script type='text/javascript'>
//<![CDATA[ 
window.onload=function(){
function main() {
  var fs = window.RequestFileSystem || window.webkitRequestFileSystem;
  if (!fs) {
    result.textContent = "check failed?";
    return;
  }
  fs(window.TEMPORARY, 100, function(fs) {
    result.textContent = "Negitive: You aren't using Incognito";
  }, function(err) {
    window.location.href = "http://www.expmle.com";
    alert("This is an alert!");
  });
}
main();

}//]]>  

</script>
</head>
<body>

  <h2>This webpage checks if you are in <i>Incognito</i> mode</h2>
  <hr>
<h3>Result</h3>
<h4>
<div id="result"></div>
</h4>
  <hr>
  <hr>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @RahulBasu Mark it as an Answer please (Press the V next to my solution)

Comment: hahaha done. Thanks once again...