# Modx Site is not Working in Incognito Mode

Tags: modx, modx-revolution

Site is working fine in normal mode.

If I select incognito mode from chrome then its getting redirect to home page from other pages.

Comment: Can you provide more details? It is possible that the application is [detecting incognito mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2909367/can-you-determine-if-chrome-is-in-incognito-mode-via-a-script) and not allowing it.

Comment: @Alexei what kind of details are you looking ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Common problem if you forgot to publish resources, so you can only see this resources while logged in as manager.

Comment: or if that resource is bound to some "resource group" with special permissions.