# chrome app proxy api always returns mode as system, even after removing proxy connection in chrome browser

Tags: google-chrome-app

I wanted to check whether system uses proxy or not to make ajax requests in chrome app.

i tried the following chrome app api

```
chrome.proxy.settings.get(
          {'incognito': false},
          function(config) {console.log((config));});
```

i am always getting this result irrespective of adding proxy in browser or not

{"levelOfControl":"controllable_by_this_extension","value":{"mode":"system"}}

mode value always as system and direct is not coming while proxy disconnected

Comment: This seems similar to this [SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2909367/can-you-determine-if-chrome-is-in-incognito-mode-via-a-script).

Comment: No just need to get proxy url is any configured in chromeos