# How can I make Angular 5 wait for a Promise used inside an Injectable's constructor to resolve before constructing dependants - or ngOnInit?

Tags: angular, promise

I have a service in my Angular 5 project that holds some configuration state:

```
@Injectable
export class FooService {

    isIncognito: boolean = null;

    constructor() {

        // I want Angular to wait for this to resolve (i.e. until `isIncognito != null`):
        FooService.isIncognitoWindow()
            .then( isIncognito => {

                this.isIncognito= isIncognito;
            } );
    }


    private static isIncognitoWindow(): Promise<boolean> {
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2909367/can-you-determine-if-chrome-is-in-incognito-mode-via-a-script
    // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/LocalFileSystem

        return new Promise<boolean>( ( resolve, reject ) => {

            let rfs = window['requestFileSystem'] || window['webkitRequestFileSystem'];
            if( !rfs ) {
                console.warn( "window.RequestFileSystem not found." );
                resolve( false );
            }

            const typeTemporary = 0;
            const typePersistent = 1;

            // requestFileSystem's callbacks are made asynchronously, so we need to use a promise.
            rfs(
                /*type: */ typeTemporary,
                /* bytesRequested: */ 100,
                /* successCallback: */ function( fso: WebKitFileSystem ) {

                    resolve( false );
                },
                /* errorCallback: */ function( err: any /* FileError */ ) {

                    resolve( true );
                }
            );
        } );
    }
}
```

This service is used by many Components in my project and is passed as a constructor argument. For example:

```
@Component( {
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: 'auth.component.html'
} )
export class AuthComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor( private fooService: FooService ) {
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {

        // do stuff that depends on `this.fooService.isIncognito != null`
    }
}
```

Ideally I'd like Angular to wait for the `FooService::isIncognitoWindow()` promise to resolve (the resolution happens instantly, but not synchronously) first before injectinting the `FooService` into the other components.

An alternative solution is changing `FooComponent.isIncognito`'s property to a `Promise<boolean>` and resolving it again and calling the rest of `ngOnInit` via a callback, but that means every component will cause the promise's main function to be invoked again - so that means possibly changing it to a buffered Observable or Subject instead, and that's getting needlessly complicated - all for a single `boolean` value. It also means refactoring lots of code I'd rather not have to do.

Comment: You could use APP_INITIALIZER token to resolve that isIncognito value before the application starts, and then in next that value to components/services

Comment: @David That sounds promising - can you repost that in an Answer with a brief example? That way I can accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you can do is use `APP_INITIALIZER` token to make sure that your `FooService` is initialised before the application starts. With the code below, angular will only start the application when the promise returned by the `load` method has resolved.

**FooService.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class FooService {

    isIncognito: boolean = null;

    public load()// <=== the method to be called and waited on during initialiation
  {
      return FooService.isIncognitoWindow().then(isIncognito =>
      {
        this.isIncognito = isIncognito;
      });

  }

    private static isIncognitoWindow(): Promise<boolean> {
    { //your method here
```

**app.module.ts**

```
export function loadFooService(fooService: FooService): Function 
{
  return () => { return fooService.load() }; 
}


@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, HelloComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ],

  providers: [ FooService,
  { provide: APP_INITIALIZER, useFactory:loadFooService , deps: [FooService], multi: true },]
})
```

See [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dyhnu3?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)!

Comment: Great Answer @David. I wish I could have upvoted it 100 times

Answer (score 0):

If `isIncognitoWindow` returns `Promise` try this:

```
      await awaitFooService.isIncognitoWindow()
            .then( isIncognito => {
                this.isIncognito= isIncognito;
            } );
```

Comment: You should not use both `await` and `then`. Decide on one or the other.