# Can a Chrome extension detect if the browser has an incognito mode?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, incognito-mode

I am looking for a way to detect, within an extension, if a Chrome browser install CAN be opened in Incognito mode: I need to find the value of **IncognitoModeAvailability**.

I am not looking to find out if the browser IS in Incognito mode. Nor am I looking to find out if the extension will work in Incognito. Nor am I trying to make an extension work in Incognito.

I'd like the Chrome extension to be able to detect if the Chrome browser install even HAS an incognito mode as a possibility. Having trouble finding anything that speaks to this.

Any assistance is appreciated!

Comment: Assuming you want to detect if it was disabled via [IncognitoModeAvailability](https://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#IncognitoModeAvailability) policy, there's no API for extensions for that. You'll have to write a separate utility, which you'll invoke using [nativeMessaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging), so it checks the various policy configs (like Windows Registry) directly and reports back to the extension.

Comment: Have you check [this SO post (Can you determine if Chrome is in incognito mode via a script?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2909367/can-you-determine-if-chrome-is-in-incognito-mode-via-a-script)?

Comment: wOxxOm, determining IncognitoModeAvailability was exactly what I was looking for, yes, though I need to be able to do it entirely within an extension rather than having a user install something else first.