# Can you determine if Chrome(latest versions above 83) is in incognito mode via a script?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, incognito-mode

Earlier we used to check for the filesystem to identify whether it is an incognito or not. But now in the latest chrome release, they have added Native file system API in incognito due to which I am unable to determine if chrome is in incognito.

Need help in determining the same using script.

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57438917/5625547) that uses the filesystem to check of incognito

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but that doesnt work in latest version of chrome