# Is there any way to check browser works with incognito mode or not by using javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, incognito-mode

I want to check browser mode by using Javascript. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2909367/can-you-determine-if-chrome-is-in-incognito-mode-via-a-script) link, but it doesn't work for new version of Chrome. Is there any **new** way to check this?

Comment: This is solved on Joe's work. Have a look!

Answer (score 4):

This is an old question, but to answer it: yes, you can still detect incognito in Chromium-based browsers. The gist is you call navigator.storage.estimate() and compare the quota property to performance.memory.jsHeapSizeLimit. If the quota is less than jsHeapSizeLimit, it's incognito.

I have a script that you can take a look at.

https://github.com/Joe12387/detectIncognito

Comment: Hello Joe, I just checked your code and works very well on the latest chrome version where I am currently working on. Thank you for your work it is very complete.