# Get ChromeOptions arguments after they have been set

Tags: java, selenium, automation

In my projects ScenarioSetup.java I am setting a few options via ChromeOptions and one of them is to open up the browser in incognito;

```
options.addArguments("--incognito");
```

Now I wanted to know if its possible to check ChromeOptions for within another class. Someone suggested to do the following, however it just throws a null pointer.

```
if (System.getProperty("chromeoptions.args").equals("--incognito")) {
  do something;
} else {
  do something else;
}
```

Comment: You can get some options by typing "chrome://version/" in the location bar and hitting enter.  (you might also use Selenium to .get() that...)  This should show any flags used at startup.

Comment: If you need to recognize the incognito mode only (not all the options ang args) see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2909367/can-you-determine-if-chrome-is-in-incognito-mode-via-a-script