# How can a Safari extension know if Private Browsing mode is on?

Tags: security, safari, privacy, safari-extension

I'm writing a Safari extension and want it to behave differently when the user turns on Private Browsing mode (I want to respect this private mode).

I found no mention of this in Apple's docs.

I'm aware of the discussion in this thread:

[Detecting if a browser is using Private Browsing mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2860879/detecting-if-a-browser-is-using-private-browsing-mode)

which suggests using a (browser-agnostic) js-CSS trick to detect private-browsing mode, but was hoping there's some hook built in to Safari that I could use for my extension.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can query the boolean `safari.application.privateBrowsing.enabled` to check if private browsing is enabled or not.

You can also attach event listeners to trigger custom code when private browsing is activated or deactivated.

```
safari.application.privateBrowsing.addEventListener('activate', function(e) {
  console.log("Private browsing activated");
});

safari.application.privateBrowsing.addEventListener('deactivate', function(e) {
  console.log("Private browsing deactivated");
});
```

Source: [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/Extensions/Reference/SafariPrivateBrowsingClassRef/SafariPrivateBrowsing/SafariPrivateBrowsing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012277)

Answer (score 0):

All private modes will ignore the current status of the cookiejar used by the browser.   Use something like an [evercookie](http://samy.pl/evercookie/) to keep track of a specific browser and how it manages its various session id's.  For instance,  if you have an http cookie that expires in 60 years,  and this cookie value isn't present in a request to your server,  then you know either the cookie values have been flushed or they are in private mode.  This will require a bit more experimentation on your side,  but this direction will be a general method to detect use of private mode in browsers.