# How to check if ios is using private browsing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, safari

One of my jquery plugins is having issues, and the issue occurs when private browsing is turned on in ios.

Is there a way to check this?

Comment: BTW: My opinion is a web app shouldn't be able to tell a difference, and it's a browser bug if it can. (This obviously doesn't solve your problem though; I wonder what's the reason.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In private mode user can't use local storage try this:

```
var storageTestKey = 'sTest',
    storage = window.sessionStorage;

try {
  storage.setItem(storageTestKey, 'test');
  storage.removeItem(storageTestKey);
} catch (e) {
  if (e.code === DOMException.QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR && storage.length === 0) {
    // private mode
  } else {
    throw e;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can't tell on iOS, but doesn't work in Chrome. Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/n49yQ/

Comment: That's because Safari and Chrome handle the idea of storage during a private session differently. Chrome will still allow **temporary** session storage when in 'incognito' mode, whereas Safari disable access completely. I prefer Chrome's implementation because HTML5 apps will still be able to cache their files/images.

Comment: @Kos Your jsfiddle does not work anymore. Here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/harianus/aueb9u74/ It alerts when Safari Prived mode is detected.

Answer (score 5):

I've found an Answear at [GitHub](https://gist.github.com/cou929/7973956) and tested it: **Working on IOS 11!**

```
var isPrivate = false;
try {
  window.openDatabase(null, null, null, null);
} catch (_) {
  isPrivate = true;
}
alert((isPrivate ? 'You\'re' : 'You aren\'t')  + ' in private browsing mode');
```

Comment: Does not appear to work anymore in IOS 13.0, but oddly enough, in IOS 13.0.1 it's fine again.