# How can I detect a change in private browsing mode

Tags: jquery, safari

I have a mobile web app, which detects private browsing mode in Safari. This works nicely when the page loads, but fails to detect when the mode changes after the page has loaded. I have tried setTimeout() to check every x seconds, but it still does not detect any changes after the page has loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another option, which I have added to a different post:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17741714/1711789

Answer (score 1):

The way I got around this was to:

1. make an ajax request to a script on the server at ask for remote ip address
2. Store the ip address in localstorage
3. Periodically make the same ajax request
4. Attempt to compare the new IP address with that in localstorage
5. As localstorage is not available in private browsing, step 4 should return false

Comment: this is a simple but in most cases efficient workaround, thx for sharing it to community

Comment: The AJAX request seems unnecessary, you could just store/retrieve anything.

Comment: BTW Safari Mobile, AFAIK, is the only one that disables LocalStorage. In Chrome and others it works fine, but it blows it away once you close the browser (it won't persist across sessions, but works fine for the same session)