# iOS Safari Private Browsing localStorage and sessionStorage Support?

Tags: javascript, ios, html, safari

I have found a few questions here on StackOverflow addressing specific functionality with iOS Safari Private Browsing and `sessionStorage` and `localStorage`. But I haven't been able to find a definitive resource denoting the support that iOS Safari has for `sessionStorage` and `localStorage` when Private Browsing.

What support is there for this or is there any specific resource from Apple denoting this functionality? The general consensus is that `localStorage` is not at all supported without a polyfill, does the same goes for `sessionStorage`?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there is any specific resource for iOS, but here's Apple's official documentation:

https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SafariJSDatabaseGuide/Name-ValueStorage/Name-ValueStorage.html

And this StackOverflow question is pretty useful as well:

[QuotaExceededError: Dom exception 22: An attempt was made to add something to storage that exceeded the quota](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21159301/quotaexceedederror-dom-exception-22-an-attempt-was-made-to-add-something-to-st)

In general, when solving for `sessionStorage` and `localStorage`, try actually developing locally with Safari on your phone with Web Inspector open. Good luck :)

Answer (score 9):

Yes, same goes for `sessionStorage` and `localStorage`.

There is an excellent Gist by Paul Irish explaining the history of the issue:

https://gist.github.com/paulirish/5558557

Best solution if you only need one of them:

```
function isLocalStorageEnabled() {
  try {
      var mod = '__storage_test__';
      localStorage.setItem(mod, mod);
      localStorage.removeItem(mod);
      return true;
  } catch(e) {
      return false;
  }
}
```

Or, to make it work for both, the MDN-recommended solution is more-generic:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API

```
function storageAvailable(type) {
    try {
        var storage = window[type];
        var x = '__storage_test__';
        storage.setItem(x, x);
        storage.removeItem(x);
        return true;
    }
    catch(e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```