# Login error while trying to read localStorage

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How do I solve the following error?

> QuotaExceededError: DOM Exception 22"

This happens while I am trying to read the `localStorage` and set the data to the header.

I am using Angular 2 client side with TypeScript.

Comment: On which navigator do you get this error ?

Comment: Please post the relevant code.

Comment: how large is the content stored in localStorage? I think the limit on most browsers is 5MB?

Comment: Content is definately under limit.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running the code in `private` or `incognito` mode. As far as i know Safari does not allow access to `localstorage` when in private mode. Perhaps you will find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21159301/quotaexceedederror-dom-exception-22-an-attempt-was-made-to-add-something-to-st#answer-27081419) answer helpful.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle or perhaps share some code?