# Launch safari browser in icognito mode programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9

Is it possible to launch safari browser in incognito mode programmatically?

Comment: As per my knowledge there is no way to do that, we can only open url in safari normal mode from the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it from your app it self (at least with public APIs) but might be possible from your web page. Check this, [Detecting if a browser is using Private Browsing mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2860879/detecting-if-a-browser-is-using-private-browsing-mode) once you load your URL in Safari, you should explicitly checkout the mode of browser, based on that you can alert user to change browser mode if require.

Comment: Actually i wanted it for facebook login through safari in app but it is not allowing to clear cookies and keeping user logge in even if user is logged out.is there any other way i can do this ? i am using facebook sdk version 4.6 which redirects me to SafariViewController by default for login in ios 9 and above.

Comment: This was (an issue) from the starting version of Facebook iOS SDK, they have given a separate method to clear cookies and session, however, in my knowledge it was not working by the time. Not sure with the latest sdk available. Btw, for this functionality what you're trying to achieve is not proper. Try looking for some other way.