# Detecting Private Browsing mode: 2019 edition

Tags: browser, privacy

It used to be the case, [as described in this answer from five years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22623958/1650379), that web sites could not reliably tell whether a client's browser was in Incognito Mode.  However, in the past few months, I've started encountering sites which are able to throw up a banner that says, "hey, you're in Private Browsing mode, so we won't show you any content."

I have two questions, which are opposite sides of the same coin:

1. As a web developer in 2019, how would I construct a reliable check for a user's Private Browsing status?
2. As a privacy-conscious web user in 2019, who might like to keep the meta-information of his privacy-consciousness private as well, how could I reliably generate a first-time-visitor experience from a site that is desperate to track me?

In pre-Incognito days I would have accomplished #2 by using a "clean profile" to visit a site that I didn't want to follow me around.  User profiles are [apparently still in Firefox](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-and-remove-firefox-profiles), though I suspect they probably don't protect against [browser fingerprinting](https://panopticlick.eff.org/).  But I'm not sure whether that is a good summary of my threat model --- my interest is mostly in opting out of the advertisement-driven data-mining ecosystem, without being treated differently for doing so.

Answer (score 1):

I'll leave the main question to others who know how each browser's Private mode may differ from default. I do use Private modes extensively, but when I encounter a page that won't work, I simply use a clean non-private window, then clear all cookies and other stored state again afterwards.

You also mention fingerprinting, which is more insidious. Often it's based on collection by a client-side script, which is detectable but only somewhat defendable in practice. But server-detectable characteristics can also provide a good enough correlation for cross-site, even cross-device correlation.

Fingerprinting is very difficult to thwart. but I recommend using Tor for as much casual browsing as practical, using multiple browsers with your activity partitioned across them in a disciplined way, using a common browser with the best fingerprinting protections or at least using the most common browser config for your platform(s), keep your browsers updated and never install Java or Flash, change your IP address(es) often, change your window size often, and clear all cookies and other stored state often. Use a common platform (machine + display size + os) if possible. Making your browser more unique by loading it up with privacy extensions is quite likely to make you look more unique. There are also a few resources out there that list fingerprinting servers / domains, and you can block those in your machine, DNS, router, or wherever practical.

Keep in mind that Panopticlick and sites like it suffer from selection bias, and also combine all platforms, obscuring how unique your browser is compared to other browsers on the same platform (it's hard to change your platform, but at least you can try to make your browser look more like others used on your platform).